# Get a description of ANativeWindow_lock error codes

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have an Android APP using Android NDK and a ANativeWindow. Sometimes, the app hangs and my logs show:

```
unable to lock window buffer (error code: -38)
```

Or

```
unable to lock window buffer (error code: -19)
```

This issue goes away if I press the power button to lock the device and again to unlock it. The app returns and starts to work OK.

The question is, I tried to search for a list of error codes returned by ANativeWindow_lock to find the meaning of this errors, but I found none.

How can I find the description of these error codes?

Thanks in advance,
Carlos Santos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe these are `INVALID_OPERATION` and `NO_INIT`.

You can find the error codes typically used internally by the Android framework [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libutils/include/utils/Errors.h).

As you can see, many of these error codes are defined as the negatives of error codes from `errno.h`. Those error codes can be found [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h) (first 34) and [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h) (the rest).

So, if for example you look up the value 19, you see that it's `ENODEV`. And the Android error code that is set to `-ENODEV` (i.e. -19) is `NO_INIT`.

Comment: Go figure, more undocumented error codes from Google.